# Solution for (504) Reason: "channel/connection is not open" in Golang amqp

Tags: go, rabbitmq, amqp

We have a client & consumer running in `Golang`. After certain time, unexpectedly the connection is dropped without any error on consumer side.
And with dropped connection, when we try to publish a message it throws following error:

> Exception (504) Reason: "channel/connection is not open

Things already confirmed:

1. Queue, exchange name and creds are correct.
2. Sometimes, even newly created connections are failing.
3. No Network Issue.

Things I suspect:

1. Might be similar to this [issue:](https://github.com/rabbitmq/amqp091-go/discussions/104) but haven't found a proper solution to this too.

Questions:

1. Lets say, the heartbeat timeout is the issue behind dropping the connection, how to set the optimal heartbeat value?
2. We also tried the retry approach where we try to use newly created instance. Now this approach is partially working. We are seeing less errors but still there are few cases where all tries failed to establish the connection.